# How to repair/waterproof Arch Top Windows

Tags: windows, leak, window-frame

We have this Arch Top Windows on top of our double pain windows. I noticed that the black seal (not sure what it exactly is) is coming out. What are my options to repair it. I am worried that will impact the integrity of the window due to leaks, water proofing etc?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Regards
Sid[image: Arch window Image attached]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it's the seal between the two panes of glass in a thermal pane window.  If that's the case, then the main concern would be getting moisture in between the panes that would cloud the glass.

There is no repair for a seal like that that I know of.  A glass shop may be able to make you a new thermal pane insert that fits into the frame.  Or try to contact the window manufacturer.

Note that my daughter has had windows like that in her house for almost 10 years now.  They have not clouded up and there is no evidence of moisture between the pans of glass.  And no indication of any other sort of leaks.

Comment: Is it possible that the stains i see which are not on the inside of house are water stains between the two panes? In that case what would be my solution (change the window?)

Comment: Yes.  If the stains aren't on the outside of either pane of glass (that is, on the inside surface or the outside surface), then they're probably on the surface between the two panes.  But the lower square window should be an independent thermal pane with it's own seals.  So even if the top window's seal has failed and is leaking, I'm not sure how that water would find its way between the lower two panes.